# How to make a connection to UIContainerView

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a standard extended UIViewController (called ParentViewController, or PVC), and want to have a container or child view which will be driven by ChildViewController or CVC.

I see that programmatically, that in PVC I can call addChild:CVC and manage calls such as didMoveToParentViewController, etc.... However, I am hoping that there is a way to do this with Interface Builder.

So I laid out an instance of PVC, then dragged a ContainerView onto PVC's view which creates a segue to a child window. In that window I assigned the class type of ChildViewController. This looks great so far, but how do I reference this programmatically from PVC? Let's try the usual: In PVC class extension, I have declared:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController* cvc;
```

When I switch to IB, and highlight the PVC instance, and select the connections inspector, I see my cvc property but I cannot hook it up to my containerView instance (even though its class type is set appropriately). It allows me to drag (draw the line), but does not let me actually hook it up. Why??

I am thinking that this just isn't possible with IB, but perhaps I'm looking at this incorrectly?

I have read [Apple's docs on child views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) and am prepared to do this programmatically if I can't get IB to do what I'm intending.

Comment: so you dont want to use segues? just want to call the container view programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cvc is a child view controller of PVC, so you can get a reference to it with the childViewControllers property, which you would do in code rather than hooking up an outlet in IB. In PVC's viewDidLoad method, do this:

```
self.cvc = (ChildViewController *)self.childViewControllers[0];
```

Xcode will not allow you to hook up outlets between two different controllers, so even though cvc is embedded as a child view controller, it's still a different view controller.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I had a feeling it would be something simple. A couple lines of code and my UI suddenly works great :)